# Why CAN a BackgroundWorker modify UI components?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm changing the `Text` of a button from a `BackgroundWorker` and it works. I thought that was supposed to throw an exception. Why doesn't it?

Why don't I get a `Cross-thread operation not valid: ... accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`?

EDIT: Thanks everyone.

Perhaps the reason was that there was a: `Thread.Sleep(1000);` on the UI.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text = "a";
}
```

However, I noticed that this following code runs fine as well, despite affecting the UI (indirectly).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int i;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        i = 1;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) ;
        button1.Text = i.ToString();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        i = 2;
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: please show your source code...

Comment: What's about this?  `for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) ; button1.Text = i.ToString();` Do you mean `for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; j++){ button1.Text = i.ToString(); }` ?

Comment: @Fuex No. The loop is to prove that the `i` is getting modified by the BGW _while the UI thread is running_. Its `Text` ends up as `2`.

Comment: @Fuex No problem. I actually wrote one with your code now (in the `Shown` event-handler) and the button's change to `2` is seen. (Thanks to an `Update()` )

Comment: Glad you found the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably that cross thread operations *can* be executed. They're just prone to trouble. And a `Control` (which is supposed to throw an exception) probably doesn't 'mind' cross threading when it's a`Sleep`.

Answer (score 5):

The callback function invoked by the background worker once work is completed (`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted`) is - for your convenience - using the UI thread dispatcher already.

**Edit:**

@ispiro: It's not guaranteed that the code in your second example will *always* work  - you still have a cross-thread update of the variable `i` so you should declare it `volatile` to make sure it is always updated correctly.

The reason the first code *should not* work is that the .NET framework helps you out detecting this cross-thread access. As @Greg D pointed out this can be disabled though (which definitely is a no-no). For more information check this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx):

> The .NET Framework helps you detect when you are accessing your
>   controls in a manner that is not thread safe. When you are running
>   your application in the debugger, and a thread other than the one
>   which created a control tries to call that control, the debugger
>   raises an InvalidOperationException with the message, "Control control
>   name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
>
> This exception occurs reliably during debugging and, under some
>   circumstances, at run time. You might see this exception when you
>   debug applications that you wrote with the .NET Framework prior to the
>   .NET Framework version 2.0. You are strongly advised to fix this
>   problem when you see it, but you can disable it by setting the
>   CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls property to false. This causes your
>   control to run like it would run under Visual Studio .NET 2003 and the
>   .NET Framework 1.1.

Comment: "The reason the first code should not work is that ..." – That, in essence, is my question. Because it _does_. And I assume that the answer is that the `Sleep` helps solve the thread conflicts. I still don't understand, though, why the second one works. (VS isn't throwing any exception in either.) Thanks a lot for the `volatile`!

Answer (score 1):

Because your callback function for the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is called (invoked) on the UI thread for convenience.  Realize though that this is not true for *every* event, obviously the `DoWork` callback runs on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities:

1)  Your program has disabled cross-thread checks.  This is a sadly common hack that software uses when people don't understand the threading rules around a UI thread.

2)  Your program is modifying the UI via the BackgroundWorker's Progress or Completed events.  These events are marshalled to the synchronization context of the thread that created the BackgroundWorker.  If the BackgroundWorker is being used in its classic context as a WinForms designer component, you're golden.  The events are getting marshalled to the UI thread for you, so you don't have to do such nonsense yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This question is sort of misleading as [BackgroundWorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) only provides *certain* guarantees. The following is a "Note" from the BGW documentation:

> You must be careful not to **[do not] manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler**. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.

The [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) and [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) events are *posted to the thread that created the BGW**. The same guarantee *does not hold* for the `DoWork` event, however: *do not access the UI from within it* :)

In essence, the code in `RunWorkerCompleted` and `ProgressChanged` is effectively automatically wrapped in [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx), which "posts a message to invoke a callback" to the dispatch queue of the window/thread.

Happy coding.

---

*Because the thread that *created* (or perhaps it's *initiated*?) the BGW effects where the callbacks will be posted, it is possible to create a BGW that will not "run" on the desired UI thread. To avoid this odd behavior, *always create/start the BGW on the UI thread that it should post back to.*

Comment: In practice, it's generally the same thread.  If we're getting C++-y technical, though, it's the thread's synchronization context.  A synchronization context can theoretically post it anywhere, it's just that practical applications will typically post it to the calling thread.  :)

Comment: @GregD That was personal experience talking :) I've accidentally created the BGW on a different thread before. Fun times.